# Is the Whitehead bracket $\pi_{p}(X)\otimes \pi_{q}(Y)\to \pi_{p+q-1}(X\vee Y)$ injective?

Tags: homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, whitehead-product

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite CW-complexes and $p,q\geq 2$. The Whitehead bracket induces a homomorphism $\pi_{p}(X)\otimes \pi_{q}(Y)\to \pi_{p+q-1}(X\vee Y)$, $\alpha\otimes \beta\mapsto [\alpha,\beta]$. Is this homomorphism always injective?

Here, I'm not assuming any higher connectedness assumptions on the spaces involved except for maybe $1$-connectedness.

Comment: Doesn't the answer to you previous question question https://mathoverflow.net/q/461440/6668 imply that in general the answer is no, because of torsion? I suspect it may be true on rational homotopy.

Comment: @GregoryArone that was easier to answer than I first thought.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-triviality of Whitehead products in wedges of CW-complexes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461440/non-triviality-of-whitehead-products-in-wedges-of-cw-complexes)

Comment: @GregoryArone My earlier question doesn't answer this one. Torsion elements can give trivial products because of bilinearity. This question is what I really meant to ask: can a Whitehead product coming from the two parts of a wedge sum be trivial for an interesting reason, namely, something other than bilinearity?

Comment: @RyanBudney see my comment to Gregory Arone.

Comment: @GregoryArone This question is precisely stated already. The older question you answered was what I didn't mean to ask because I had overlooked the interaction of torsion and bilinearity. I don't feel it's necessary to write out the definition of the tensor product here but the use of the tensor product precisely encodes the issue of bilinearity.

Comment: For those voting to close as a duplicate please point out where this question has been answered. It is unclear to me how this could be confused with the much simpler question  linked to in the comments.

Comment: @J.K.T. You are right, apologies. I withdrew my vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is (still) no. It comes down to the assertion that the homomorphism $\pi_p(A)\otimes \pi_q(B)\to \pi_{p+q}(A\wedge B)$ is not always injective.

To see this, let us rewrite the Whitehead product as a Samelson product. There is a natural map
$\Omega X \wedge \Omega Y\to \Omega(X\vee Y).$
It is essentially the commutator of the two inclusion maps. From this we obtain a composition of homomorphisms
$$ \pi_{p}(\Omega X)\otimes \pi_{q}(\Omega Y) \to \pi_{p+q}(\Omega X\wedge \Omega Y)\to \pi_{p+q}(\Omega(X\vee Y)).$$
This homomorphism is equivalent to the Whitehead bracket as defined in the OP. So to find an example when the Whitehead bracket is not injective it is enough to find an example where the homomorphism $ \pi_{p}(\Omega X)\otimes \pi_{q}(\Omega Y) \to \pi_{p+q}(\Omega X\wedge \Omega Y)$ is not injective. Let's take $X=S^{m+1}, Y=S^{n+1}$. Recall that there is a $2m-1$-connected map $S^m\to \Omega S^{m+1}$. From this, we obtain a diagram of groups
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\pi_p(S^m) \otimes \pi_q(S^n) & \to & \pi_{p+q}(S^{m}\wedge S^n) \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\pi_{p}(\Omega S^{m+1})\otimes \pi_q(\Omega S^{n+1}) & \to & \pi_{p+q}(\Omega S^{m+1}\wedge \Omega S^{n+1}).
\end{array}
$$
When $p< 2m-1$ and $q<2n-1$, the left vertical homomorphism is an isomorphism, and the homotopy groups are in the stable range. To find an element in the kernel of the bottom homomorphism, choose two elements in the stable homotopy groups of spheres whose tensor product is not zero, but whose smash product is zero. For example $\eta$ and $\nu$. Then realise them as unstable homotopy groups of spheres of high enough dimension.

Comment: Wow, thank you. It take it that $\eta$ generates $\pi_{3}(S^2)$ but where is $\nu$?

Comment: The analogous element of $\pi_7(S^4)$